# How to get string following a certain pattern?

Tags: regex

I have a URL:

```
https://fakedomain.com/2017/07/01/the-string-i-want-to-get/
```

I can recognize the `2017/07/01/` via this pattern:

`(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/)`

But what I want, is the string that comes after it: `the-string-i-want-to-get/`.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: `\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/(.*)` ? Or, if you want to match only until the next "/": `\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/(.*)\/`. The result you're looking for is on the only group in the regex.

Comment: Does whichever language you're using not provide a better way to parse an url than regex? Maybe just split on `/`, in fact?

Comment: @maroun Thanks! write it as an answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the language you're using, you might find a library that does that for you (instead of writing your own regex). Anyway, if you want to achieve this by regex, you can:

```
\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/(.*)\/
```

This will catch anything after the date, up to the next "/".

You can also use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/)(.*)\/
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this regex, which matches `2017/07/01/` in the first group and `the-string-i-want-to-get/` in the second group:

```
(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/)(.*/)
```

Here is an implementation example in Python3:

```
import re

url = 'https://fakedomain.com/2017/07/01/the-string-i-want-to-get/'

m = re.search(r'(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/)(.*/)', url)

print(m.group(1))  # 2017/07/01/
print(m.group(2))  # the-string-i-want-to-get/
```